# CSS Animation not working in IOS 8 (Fine in IOS 7 and generally)

Tags: css, ios7, ios8, slideshow

I have made a slideshow animation in CSS using some code kindly posted here:https://gist.github.com/leemark/11237860  to make slideshows for my website.

The slideshow animations work fine in all the browsers I have tried and on iPhone and iPad running IOS 7. It does not work on iPad running IOS 8 and I can't figure out why.

Here is the CSS:

Thank you very much!

```css
/* http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/ */
.css-slideshow {
position: relative;
max-width: 495px;
height: 370px;
margin: 1em auto .5em auto;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
margin: 0;
max-width: 495px;
height: 370px;
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
color: #fff;
background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
font-size: .8em;
padding: 8px 12px;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s;
-o-transition: opacity .5s;
-ms-transition: opacity .5s;
transition: opacity .5s;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s;
-o-transition: opacity .5s;
-ms-transition: opacity .5s;
transition: opacity .5s;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
max-width: 530px;
text-align: right;
font-size: .7em;
font-style: italic;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(6),.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 42s  infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 42s  infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(6) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(8) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
-moz-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
-ms-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
-o-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes "xfade" {
 0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
 }
14.67% {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
16.67% {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
 98% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes xfade {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
14.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
16.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
 98% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "xfade" {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
14.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
16.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
 98% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes "xfade" {
 0% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
14.67% {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
16.67% {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
 98% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes "xfade" {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
14.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}
16.67% {
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
 98% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Aside: [You only really require the `-webkit-` prefix for CSS animations, including the keyframes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation). As far as I am aware, there has never been an `-ms-` or `-o-` prefix for animations at all.

Comment: You may be right, I'm fairly new to this, but as that bit is working fine on Opera and MicroSoft I'm not too worried about it, it's Safari on IOS 8 that's the problem at the moment. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem will be the quotes around the keyframe name: `@-webkit-keyframes "xfade"`. 
It should be `@-webkit-keyframes xfade`.

#### General Observations

- There is no need for the IE opacity filters, the `opacity` property is [supported IE9 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity) and CSS animation is [only supported in IE10 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) so the opacity property will be supported if the animation is recognised.
- [You only really require the -webkit- prefix for CSS animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), remove the other prefixed properties and improve the readability of your CSS — it will help prevent mistakes
- The unprefixed `@keyframes` should be after the `-webkit-` prefixed keyframes, so supporting browsers will use the standard.

#### Complete Example

I have not tested this in iOS, but I am fairly certain this should work with no problems.

```css
.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 1em auto .5em auto;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 530px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  opacity: 0;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/000000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/000000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/000000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/000000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FF0000" width="495" height="370" />
    <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption>
  </figure>



</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post that. Unfortunately when I changed my code to match yours and uploaded it, it still did not work in IOS 8.